# No module named setuptools.config

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-bouncy, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I tried to follow the instructions to install ROS2 using colcon and I get the following error (even though the build continue and pass):

> [0.639s]
> ERROR:colcon.colcon_core.entry_point:Exception
> loading extension
> 'colcon_core.package_identification.python':
> No module named 'setuptools.config'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/entry_point.py", line 98, in load_entry_points
> extension_type = load_entry_point(entry_point)   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/entry_point.py", line 140, in load_entry_point
> return entry_point.load()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
> line 2229, in load
> return self.resolve()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
> line 2235, in resolve
> module = **import**(self.module_name, fromlist=['**name**'], level=0)   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/package_identification/python.py",
> line 10, in 
> from setuptools.config import read_configuration ImportError: No
> module named 'setuptools.config'

With the following command:

```
colcon build --symlink-install
```

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04 and followed this link https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Linux-Development-Setup
Do I need to specify something to remove this error ?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296433/no-module-named-setuptools.config/) by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 527 on 2018-07-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-05**:
What version of setuptools do you have installed? `python3 -m pip freeze --all | grep setuptools`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah! Yes I guess it was too old as explained in https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/512
My version was setuptools==20.7.0 and after the "sudo -H python3 -m pip install -U setuptools" it is now setuptools==39.2.0. thanks !

---

Originally posted by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) with karma: 527 on 2018-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3